# Realm class name different from Stored Name in DB

Tags: swift, realm

So I am having naming conflicts in my code.

I have

```
struct LocationMessage {}
```

and

```
class LocationMessageRLM : Object {}
```

Is there an annotation or configuraiton option that will allow my `LocationMessageRLM` object to be stored in a table called `LocationMessage`

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. Realm generates the object schema for each table at runtime based off the class names of every `Object` subclass. There are no configuration options to change this behaviour.

If you're not happy about the name of the Realm object table, it might be worth considering renaming the struct instead (Sorry if that was really obvious!).

Comment: Unfortunately i'm running into struct naming conflicts which is why i ask.  I was hoping there was an annotation or something to just change what the DB is stored as.  Now i will try to have to separate things into different modules